# Using a concatenated value of two columns to display data

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use a concatenated value of two columns to display data. I'm first testing out ways to do this in a query before actually using it in a stored proc but I just don't get any results back.
So I have a table called Person:

```
    CREATE TABLE Person
    (
     IDNumber   char(13)     NOT NULL,
     Name       varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
     Surname    varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
     Age        int          NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (IDNumber)
    )
```

I want to display all the data available if the concatenated value of Name and Surname is equal to say 'Harriet West' but I'm not sure how to do this. Can anyone help by explaining how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a computed column such as:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    IDNumber   char(13)     NOT NULL,
    Name       varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
    Surname    varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
    Age        int          NOT NULL,
    Fullname AS Name + ' ' + Surname,
    PRIMARY KEY (IDNumber)
)
```

Example

```
INSERT INTO Person (IDNumber, Name, Surname, Age) 
VALUES ('1', 'Bob', 'Smith', 10);
```

You can then query the computed column:

```
SELECT [column list] FROM Person WHERE Fullname = 'Bob Smith';
```

Result

```
|      IDNUMBER | NAME | SURNAME | AGE |  FULLNAME |
|---------------|------|---------|-----|-----------|
| 1             |  Bob |   Smith |  10 | Bob Smith |
```

[Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Some other thoughts:

- It seems silly to give `IDNumber` a string data type; perhaps call it something else?
- Do you really need `varchar(max)` for name columns?
- Don't store a *calculated* value. You should store the date of birth of the person, then calculate the age.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot and was easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

I like the computed column approach, but if you don't want it, in your query you can do:

```
SELECT IDNumber, Name, Surname, Name + ' ' + Surname [Full Name], Age
FROM Person
```

If you want to query by the Full Name you could do:

```
SELECT IDNumber, Name, Surname, Age
FROM Person
WHERE Name + ' ' + Surname = 'Harriet West'
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83baf/1)</kbd>

Comment: I think the OP is trying to query the concatenated value.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO. Thanks. I re-read it and i think you are right

Answer (score 0):

In the where clause...

```
Select * from Person
Where SurName + ' ' + Name = 'Harriet West'
```

Be sure to set concat_null_yields_null Off if there is a chance that SurName or Name could be Null.